# retriving user information through Paypal Javascript login button

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

i have integrated paypal login button (javascript button) and when i am clicking on it its getting to the paypal site for authentication.

following is my code for paypal button

```
       <span id="paypal"></span>

  <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/api.js"></script>
  <script>
    var url = document.URL;
    paypal.use( ["login"], function(login) {
       login.render ({
       "appid": "***",
       "authend": "sandbox",
        "scopes": "profile email address phone https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes",
        "containerid": "paypal",
        "locale": "en-us",
        "returnurl": "http://stereotribes.dev/login"
           });
      });
  </script>
```

after successful authentication its redirecting me to my server url again.

now my question is how to receive user information after authentication done.

i have searched around paypal site but i am not getting the clear idea to retrieve user informatoin.

can anybody help me in this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting 1 day i came up with the following code(solution), hope it may save someone's time ...

in my return url ("http://stereotribes.dev/login") i have written following code ...

```
if($_REQUEST['code']) {
    $model->getPaypalEmail($_REQUEST['code']);
}
```

**`$_REQUEST['code'] (token)`** will be send by paypal and same code we have send back via curl to confirm identity...

```
public function getPaypalEmail($code){
    if($code){
        $strGetCodePaypalLoginDetails = $code;

        if ($strGetCodePaypalLoginDetails != '') {
            // Change this curl_init url according to your environment.
            $ch = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice");
            $flag_result = 1;
            curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'client_id=********&client_secret=*****&grant_type=authorization_code&code=' . $strGetCodePaypalLoginDetails,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
                    )
            );

            $arrResponse = curl_exec($ch);

            if ($arrResponse === false) {
                $arrResponseToken = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
                $flag_result = 0;
            } else {
                //Operation completed without any errors
                $arrResponse = json_decode($arrResponse);
                $strAccess_Token = $arrResponse->{'access_token'};

                // Change this curl_init url according to your environment.
                $chToken = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=openid&access_token=" . $strAccess_Token);

                curl_setopt_array($chToken, array(
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
                        )
                );

                $arrResponseToken = curl_exec($chToken);

                if ($arrResponseToken === false) {
                    $arrResponseToken = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($chToken);
                    $flag_result = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        $arrResponseToken = json_decode($arrResponseToken, true);

        print_r($arrResponseToken); //here you will get info from paypal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).  It will POST transaction data to a listener script you have configured on your server immediately when transactions happen, so you can automate tasks like updating your database, sending email notifications, etc. in real-time.

If you need data available on your return URL you can use [Payment Data Transfer (PDT)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/), which is very similar to IPN.  The only thing about that is if people don't make it back to your return URL for some reason then that code will never run, so it's not recommended that you do any database updates, email notifications, or anything like that from your return URL.

Again, IPN will be triggered regardless of whether they make it back, so you can rest assured that code will run as expected.

Comment: here i am not making any payment. i just want user information as email, address etc..

Comment: That is what I explained.  When you receive payments, IPN will be triggered, and it will contain all of the detail you need about the payer.